# Print web page source code in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, urllib

I want to print a web page source code but python print command just prints empty space and I think it's because of its large size. Is there any way to print page source code in shell or at list in a file?
I've tried printing in a file but this error occurred:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u06cc' in position 11826: character maps to <undefined>
```

How can I fix it?

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.farsnews.com')
html = response.read()

print(html)#prints empty space! 

hf=open('test.txt','w')
a=str(html,'utf-8')
hf.write(a)
hf.close()
```

Python easily prints `a[0:1000]` but for `a[0:len(a)]` as I said empty space!

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams What do you mean?

Comment: Works for me (the webpage source code is displayed); I'm using Python 3.3.1 running on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @Ramchandra Apte I'm using python 3.3.2 running windows 7 and I faced unicode error.

Comment: I tested it and for me it worked fine. I'm running on Debian jessie with python 3.3.2+. I would guess your terminal can't display some characters in the source code or the charmaps of your OS don't support them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried the same on Win7 using python 3.2.5 and here's what I got:

```
Python 3.2.5 (default, May 15 2013, 23:07:10) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from urllib import request
>>> r = request.urlopen("http://www.farsnews.com")
>>> bytecode = r.read()
>>> htmlstr = bytecode.decode()
>>> print(bytecode)
```

Printing `bytecode` works well as it prints the encoded representations
for unicode chars but printing the `htmlstr` raises the `UnicodeDecodeError`
on windows because some chars cannot be printed using current locale's
default encoding (windows' cmd.exe is not unicode)

In my case the encoding that has been used was `'cp866'` as I saw it in traceback.

By default py3k uses the `'utf-8'` encoding to store string data and if you want to override it you should explicitly specify the encoding to use for decoding

So here's the possibble workaround:

```
>>> safe_str = bytecode.decode(encoding='cp866', errors='ignore')
>>> print(safe_str)
```

Actually, it's equivalent to

```
>>> safe_str = str(bytecode, encoding='cp866', errors='ignore')
>>> print(safe_str)
```

The second parameter `errors` tells whether the error should be rose when
the encoding you're trying to use cannot decode the particular character

Answer (score 0):

I simply did

```
import requests
page = requests.get(url)
print (page.text.encode('utf8'))
```

If you're scraping websites with python then is [this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) an awesome starting point.  I also recommend that you look into BeautifulSoup (another method of parsing html).