# Python - Page Source when calling a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im looking for a really simple code to call a url and print the html source code. This is what I am using. Im following an online course which has the code

```
def get_page(url):
try:
    import urllib
    return urllib.open(url).read()
except:
    return ""

print(get_page('https://www.yahoo.com/'))
```

Prints nothing but also no errors.  Alternatively from browsing these forums I've tried

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

print (urlopen('https://xkcd.com/353/'))
```

when I do this I get

```
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x000001E947559710>
```

Comment: Check this out [print source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20354633/3126771)

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen    
print (urlopen('https://xkcd.com/353/').read().decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming UTF-8 encoding was used

```
from urllib import request
def get_src_code(url):
    r = request.urlopen("url")
    byte_code = r.read()
    src_code = bytecode.decode()
    return src_code
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints the empty string at the `except` block. Your code is generating error because there is no attribute called `open` in `urllib` module. You can't see the error because you are using a `try-except` block which is returning an empty string on every error. In your code, you can see the error like this:

```
def get_page(url):
    try:
        import urllib
        return urllib.open(url).read()
    except Exception as e:
        return e.args[0]
```

To get your expected output, do it like this:

```
def get_page(url):
    try:
        from urllib.request import urlopen
        return urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        return e.args[0]
```